# How do I fix feed error?

Tags: rss

I'm getting a feed error of 'XML parsing error: :[line number]:0: junk after document element'.

Although such errors often seem to be from unwanted code injections, mine is showing 'Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by'... which I've previously had with unwanted white space.

'Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ...path to... /wp-includes/feed-rss2.php:11) in ...path to custom theme... /feed-rss2.php on line 3<.'

The two files noted in the error, are identical to those in other installs which don't have this error - which seems to trigger at the end of the last-but-one item in the feed.

Answer (score 0):

That depends of what that incomplete path `path to... /feed-rss2.php` contains. Could be a Plugin, a Theme, a white space in a file, or any syntactic error while modifying or adding something.

It is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag (`?>`) at the end of the files, in files with pure PHP code, to avoid such probability.

This is a common cause of errors with described error message.

> Making a Backup before changes in files is ***highly recommended*** to
>   prevent loosing your content.

Comment: Thanks. Those paths are to wp-includes/feed-rss2.php and a modified variant thereof in the custom theme... which is used with a custom function. All files are identical to those used in another install.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Seems the code in my functions was the issue - even though it was a direct cut/paste of that working on in another install. Strange.